# Would a tag lower-bounds be useful?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There have been some questions about lower bounds on complexities, which are often hard to obtain. As there are techniques that can be used in many scenarios, it might be useful to connect such questions with [lower-bounds](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lower-bounds).

What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. That seems to be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any harm in having a tag for lower bounds in complexity theory, i.e. $\Omega$. Assuming that's what you mean by the tag. I'm a bit worried that the tag name looks ambiguous, but not so much that a wiki excerpt wouldn't fix.

Answer (score 1):

Something about that seems unsatisfactory to me.

- The tag is a very general subcategory of complexity, not specific enough to be useful (IMHO)
- Having a tag for lower-bounds and not upper-bounds is asymmetric, hence hateful

If there are specific techniques which are particularly well-suited to proving lower-bounds, I suggest we have tags for the techniques.

Then again, I don't think there's any harm in having this particular tag, but I don't see it being particularly useful. Noise, not signal.

Comment: I find the [lower-bounds tag on cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lower-bounds) to be useful. Why would it not be useful here, too?

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev Like I said, I don't see any particular harm in it, I'm just not sure that it's going to be a particularly valuable tag. I mean, 2% of questions on CS Theory have that tag, and ~2/3 of those are also tagged "cc.complexity-theory". While I guess it isn't a useless tag there, I'd hesitate to argue that it's adding much to that site, where it might be expected to add more anyway.